# ASP.NET MVC Using JQuery DatePicker with model binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, binding

I am trying to bind the date selected by the DatePicker to the model that is strongly typed to my view.  The property inside the model (NewEditDataTypeModel) that I'm trying to bind to is "codeTypeNewEditModel.EffectStartDate".  The datatype is DateTime.

**My view is strong typed as follows:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TMS.MVC.BusinessSystemsSupport.Models.NewEditDataTypeModel>" %>
```

** My DatePicker is setup as follows:**

```
Effective Start Date: <input type="text" id="Model_codeTypeNewEditModel_EffectStartDate" name="Model_codeTypeNewEditModel_EffectStartDate"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Model_codeTypeNewEditModel_EffectStartDate").datepicker({
  showOn: 'button',
  buttonImage: '/Content/images/calendar.gif',
  duration: 0 
});
});
```

**My action method is as follows:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DataTypeNewEdit(NewEditDataTypeModel newEditDataTypeModel)
    {  etc
```

The newEditDataTypeModel model doesn't populate the effected start date from the DatePicker.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  I believe using the underscores is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have `Model` as a prefix for the input name.

The name of the input must use dot to indicate a property. Not underscore

So if you will replace:

```
<input type="text" id="Model_codeTypeNewEditModel_EffectStartDate" name="Model_codeTypeNewEditModel_EffectStartDate"/>
```

with

```
<input type="text" id="Model_codeTypeNewEditModel_EffectStartDate" name="newEditDataTypeModel.EffectStartDate"/>
```

It should work for you.

Here, `newEditDataTypeModel` should be equal to the parameter on the action.

But I would just take advantage of strongly type helpers and use `Html.TextBoxFor`.

Comment: 'First of all, you say that your view is strongly type, but according to the code it is not.' this is what I was about to post but then I clicked edit and saw that because he hadn't used code formatting the content after `...ViewUserControl` was getting trimmed out due to the `<`. Anyway, this is the correct answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect that. Also added another option for you at the end. Mind to accept the answer then?